# Angular custom directive calling another custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing an angular framework where user can configure header, menu, footer and selected pages using custom directives. To complete this requirement, at one point I need the following. I have seen example on the net, but does not really explain it well.

The requirement is that the templateUrl of the first custom directive shall be replaced with a template attribute that should call another custom directive.

The following code with templateUrl works fine.

```
angular.module("app",[]);
angular.module("app").controller("productController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {


}]);

angular.module("app").directive("tmHtml", function () {
    return {
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
        },
        controller: "productController",
        templateUrl: "/templates/HideShow.html"
    };
});
```

However, when I change the above code as follows. I am making the change so that my custom directive tmHtml calls another custom directive.

```
 angular.module("app").directive("tmHtml", function () {
        return {
            transclude: false,
            scope: {
            },
            controller: "productController",
         template: ``<hideShow></hideShow>``
        };
    });
```

New Directive for hideShow is written as follows

```
angular.module("app").directive("hideShow", function () {

    return {
        tempateUrl: "/templates/HideShow.html"
    };

});
```

It's not working. I understand I am missing something here. I could not find out. Appreciate help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('productController', function($scope) {

});

app.directive("hideShow", function() {

  return {
    templateUrl: "hideshow.html"
  };

});


app.directive("tmHtml", function() {
  return {
    transclude: false,
    scope: {},
    controller: "productController",
    template: "<hide-show></hide-show>"
  };
});
```

the problem is with the spelling of `templateUrl` in your `hideShow` directive.

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/TaznOeNQ7dM9lyFgqwCL?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try define your controller with controllerAs:

```
angular.module("app").directive("tmHtml", function () {
    return {
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
        },
        controllerAs: "productController",
        templateUrl: "/templates/HideShow.html"
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 angular.module("app").directive("tmHtml", function () {
        return {
            transclude: false,
            scope: {
            },
            controller: "productController",
         template: ``<hideShow></hideShow>``
        };
    });
```

must be replaced by

```
 angular.module("app").directive("tmHtml", function () {
        return {
            transclude: false,
            scope: {
            },
            controller: "productController",
         template: "<hide-show></hide-show>"
        };
    });
```

under the attribute `template`, you add Html. So, you still have to  use snake-case there, like  in your Html files

Comment: I am using the following directive in my HTML code <tm-html><tm-html>. This in turn calls hideShow directive.

Comment: this is what you said in your question : `template: <hideShow></hideShow>`

Comment: Not all directives are `element-directive`s. The docs even note that `Note: When you create a directive, it is restricted to attribute and elements only by default. In order to create directives that are triggered by class name, you need to use the restrict option. `

Comment: @SalathielGenèse so, there should not be any issue with it, because default restrict is `'AE'`, and OP is using the directive as Element

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe Thanks. I have edited the post to add clarity. Hope this helps to help

Comment: @SankarKrishnamoorthy answer updated for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

Your first directive may have an [eventually scoped](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) attribute that you [observe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe).

Then it may wrap the second directive. If needed, your directives may [communicates](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate) as parents and children.